# Lerna, conventional commits and long term support releases

Tags: javascript, lerna, monorepo, lts

We have a number of packages in a monorepo, managed by Lerna and with mandatory conventional commits. While everyone's on the same page at the HEAD of master/latest version, things work great. But we now have a need for creating long term support releases, i.e. a major release that we keep backporting fixes to.

How is this supposed to work with Lerna? E.g.

1. Say I have **a@1.0.0** and **b@1.0.0** and **b** depends on **a**.
2. I make a breaking change to **a** and publish giving me **a@2.0.0** and also **b@1.0.1** due to the version bump.
3. I discover a bug in **a**, fix it on master and publish which creates **a@2.0.1** and also **b@1.0.2**.
4. I create a branch from point 1 above and backport the fix (for purposes of long term support). When I publish it correctly tries to create **a@1.0.1** but fails when trying to create **b@1.0.1** since that version already exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?